# Riesz's lemma to his representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $H^*$ be the dual space of $H$.

The Riesz lemma states that for each $T\in H^*$, there is a unique $y_T\in H$ such that $T(x)=(y_T,x)$ $\forall x\in H$. Also, $||y_T||_H$ = $||T||_{H^*}$.

This doesn't show that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the hilbert space $H$ and its dual space $H^*$.

So, to derive the one-to-one correspondence between $H$ and $H^*$, we need to show that for each $y\in H$, then there exists an unique $T_y \in H$ such that $T_y(x)=(y,x)$ $\forall x \in H$.

I was thinking about showing that $T_y(x)=(y,x)$  for some subspace(s) (whose span is $H$). But I wasn't successful in doing this. I'm also thinking about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show an equality (by showing an inequality in both directions...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The map $H \to H^{\ast}$ given by $y \mapsto (y,\cdot)$ is clearly injective (it is isometric, for example) and it is surjective by what you call the Riesz lemma.

Comment: By the way: By stating "For each ... there exists a unique ..." you are already implying that there is a bijection. To spell it out completely: "for each ... there exists ..." implies onto, "unique" implies one-to-one.

Comment: Thanks Theo. Do you then think there is any point in proving the converse I stated above:  for each y∈H, then there exists an unique Ty∈H such that Ty(x)=(y,x) ∀x∈H. ?

Comment: Well, there is nothing to prove $T_y(\cdot) = (y,\cdot)$. Every other linear functional is of the form $(y', \cdot)$ by the Riesz lemma. Since for $z = y - y'$ we have $(y,z) - (y',z) = \|z\|^2$ we must have $z = 0$ if the two functionals are the same, i.e. $y = y'$.

Comment: "for each y∈H, then there exists an unique Ty∈H such that Ty(x)=(y,x) ∀x∈H": Well, $T_y$ is _defined_ by the above formula; you just have to check that it's a linear and bounded functional (which is quite easy). It's like asking "Why is there a (unique) function $f$ such that $f(x)=x^2 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still don't understand the source of confusion here. You can find a proof of the Riesz representation theorem in (the second part of) [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43174/a-proof-of-the-riesz-representation-theorem/43177#43177) which is essentially the same as the proof of Theorem 3.2.3 on [p.89](http://books.google.com/books?id=a1R0livwR9AC&pg=PA89) of Pedersen's *[Analysis Now](http://books.google.com/books?id=a1R0livwR9AC)*. Any other basic book on functional analysis will contain a proof.

Look: The Riesz lemma you state tells you that *every* linear functional $T \in H^{\ast}$ is of the form $T(x) = (y_T,x)$ for a *unique* $y_T \in H$.

This means that the map $H \to H^{\ast}$ given by $y \mapsto (y,\cdot)$ is

1. *onto* — because *every* continuous linear functional is of this form, and it is
2. *one-to-one* — either because it is *isometric* (as $\|T\| = \|y_T\|$) — or directly because for $y \neq y'$ we can take $z = y - y' \neq 0$, hence $(y,z) - (y',z) = (z,z) = \|z\|^2 \neq 0$, so $(y,\cdot) \neq (y',\cdot)$.

Now the lemma you want to prove is a triviality: we already *have* a bijection $y \to (y,\cdot)$ between $H$ and $H^{\ast}$.

Given $y \in H$ the map $T_y$ defined by $x \mapsto T_y(x) = (y,x)$ *is* a linear functional and it is already of the desired form $T_y = (y,\cdot)$. It is continuous of norm $\|T_y\| \leq \|y\|$ by Cauchy–Schwarz and plugging $y$ into the definition gives $T_y(y) = (y,y) = \|y\|^2$, so we see that $\|T_y\| \geq \|y\|$, hence $\|T_y\| = \|y\|$.

So $T_y = (y,\cdot)$ *is* a continuous linear functional and by repeating the second argument in 2. above we see that we *must have* $y_{T_y} = y$ (we can appeal to the uniqueness part of the Riesz lemma, too of course).